# find closest fortnight date in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

In Colombia salaries are paid (mostly) fortnightly, the 15th and the last day of month. I'm trying to generate a new variable from the date of a sale, which I expect to be highly correlated with the volume of sales: **number of days since last pay-day**, which I can calculate as a simple difference once I have the pay-day date.

I have a data frame `a` of sales with their dates from which we only care for sales dates, like this:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(1423121832, 1423988603, 1424779384, 
1425132001, 1427800333), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), .Names = "date", row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I wanted to generate a vector of *the closest* pay-day to each date, but have been unable to deal with the end of each month. I solved the rest by:

```
library(lubridate)
cbind(a, 
      basedate = as.Date(
                   ifelse(day(a$date) %in% c(15:31), 
                          floor_date(a$date, "month")+(3600*24*14), 
                          floor_date(a$date, "month") - (3600 * 24)) / (3600 * 24), 
                   origin = origin))
```

From which I get:

```
                 date   basedate
1 2015-02-05 07:37:12 2015-01-31
2 2015-02-15 08:23:23 2015-02-15
3 2015-02-24 12:03:04 2015-02-15
4 2015-02-28 14:00:01 2015-02-15
5 2015-03-31 11:12:13 2015-03-15
```

That basedate vector is incorrect in rows 4 and 5. I want the last two `basedate`'s to be `2015-02-28` and `2015-03-31`. I'm aware I could get it by nesting another `ifelse` in the code I have, but am pretty sure there is **the** easy way, and I just haven't met it.

How can I correctly determine the closest fortnight (pay-day) to a date?
(I would prefer a `base` or `lubridate` solution. However any other package that handles the problem is welcome)

Comment: "number of days since last pay-day", "closest pay-day to each date" - decide for one of those.

Comment: @Roland thanks for your comment. I already did: "wich I can calculate as a simple difference once I have the pay-day date". That means I need to know how to calculate the closest pay-day date, the rest I could do myself

Comment: Now, if there's a way to calculate the number of days since last pay-day **without** calculating the closest pay-day, then I'd like to learn that too!

Comment: I don't understand why you are interested in the closest pay-day. You need to know the **last** pay-day if you want to calculate the time since then.

Comment: @Roland, this may be an issue of naming... I need the closest payday to any given date, so for may vector of sales dates I would know how many days **had** elapsed since the _last_ payday at the time. I thought that if i called the variable "last payday" then someone could relate it to actual date **only**.

Comment: Well, "closest pay-day" could be a future pay-day. So, it's ambivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lubridate` you can create an index indicating days after the 14th and days before in the current month. With that index, find the last payday. Finally, you can calculate the difference between the paydate and the current date:

```
library(lubridate)
d <- as.Date(df$date)
islastday <- d == (ceiling_date(d, unit="month") - 1)
isbefore15 <- as.integer(format(df$date, '%e'))/15 < 1L
payday <- Sys.Date()
for(i in 1:length(d)) {
  payday[i] <- if(islastday[i]) {
              d[i]
  } else if(isbefore15[i]) {
    floor_date(d[i], unit="month") - 1L

  } else {  floor_date(d[i], unit="month") + 14L 

  }
}

df$payday <- payday
df$difference <- as.Date(df$date) - df$payday
df
#                  date     payday difference
# 1 2015-02-05 07:37:12 2015-01-31     5 days
# 2 2015-02-15 08:23:23 2015-02-15     0 days
# 3 2015-02-24 12:03:04 2015-02-15     9 days
# 4 2015-02-28 14:00:01 2015-02-28     0 days
# 5 2015-03-31 11:12:13 2015-03-31     0 days
```

**Update**

Faster solution:

```
d2 <- d
d2[isbefore15] <- floor_date(d[isbefore15], unit="month") - 1L
d2[!isbefore15] <- floor_date(d[!isbefore15], unit="month") + 14L 
df$payday <- d2
df$difference <- as.Date(df$date) - df$payday
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think we're achieving the same, just I did via `ifelse` and you via `for`. Consequently, your `payday` vector also has wrong dates in rows 4 and 5 (see mine in the post). They should have been feb 28th and march 31st (as they are actual last day of month, so it **is** payday). Correct differences would be `c(4, 0, 9, 0, 0)`

Comment: Answered too quickly. You can adjust the index

Comment: would you please elaborate? how can I adjust it?

Comment: You can find if the day is the last of the month with "ceiling_date(df$date) - 1"

Comment: I your expected output for the first date should be 5

Comment: This solution works. Problem is, I have more than 1 million rows, so the loop takes forever. I wondered if there was any vectorized solution.

Comment: Update posted. If you would like any other adjustments made feel free to hire a consultant.